# match full string against regex is not working properly

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test full string against regex and return false is it doesnt pass the test

but it seems that if some of the string pass the test I get true

```
   const regexp = new RegExp(
  `^([\\\\a-z0-9+.-]+?:((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)@)?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)(?::(\\d*))?(\\/(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\\/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?|(\\/?(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})+(?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@\\/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)(?:\\?((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?(?:#((?:[a-z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:\\/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*))?$`,"i")

    regexp.test("/test{}") // output true
```

I expect the test to be false cuz "{}" is not a valid signs in the uri

Comment: You can test and improve your regular-expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: been there couldnt get any solution from there

Comment: I guess the expression is not made by you, am I right? So update your question showing some examples of URI you want to check and which one should be accepted and which one not. Your posted expression is very complicated and almost undebugable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Regex I used have several capture groups

ex: `^(imaCaptureGroup1)*(\w)$` see that `(\w)` is "captureGroup2" so when I do `regex.test("2")`

even though I made a ^ so my regex will enforce start with "imaCaptureGroup1"
since its a capture group it just skips it and searchs for the next capture group `(\w)` and it rightly returns true

Answer (score 0):

Putting your regular expression in regex101 reveals which parts are found. The `{}` at the end are ignored.

[image: regex101 screenshot with your RegEx]

This probably just means your regular expression is over-engineered. What is the goal?
What pattern are you trying to match?